# Spring integration + JMS + getting ClassCast exception in service activator

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-jms

I am using Spring integration to connect to JMS Messaging queues.
JMS Provider I am using is Apache ActiveMQ.

I have following class which reads JMS messages (having `ServiceActivator` method):

```
@Component
public class MessageReader
{

@ServiceActivator
public Entity onMessage(Message<Entity> inboundMessage) {

    System.out.println(" -------Message Read Start--------");

    System.out.println(inboundMessage.getHeaders());

    System.out.println(" -------Message Headers Reading completed--------");

    Entity payload = null;


    try{

        payload = inboundMessage.getPayload();
        System.out.println(" -------Message Read End--------");
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return payload;
}
}
```

Over here, Entity is a POJO in my application.

While reading message from JMS-queue, I get following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQObjectMessage cannot be cast to com.poc.pojo.Entity
```

How should I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use the framework(s) incorrectly; you need to show the full stack trace and exactly how you are configuring the app.

Answer (score 0):

See your stacktrace, ClassCastException,

- First see your Entity, what interface has implement?
- Second inboundMessage.getPayload().getClass(), implement same interface ActiveMQ required?

  - Solution for  this the both class implement same interface.
  - Other reader one class make a converter other class.
  - Other problema, spring configuration correct for use integration ActiveMQ

Comment: Entity class implements only serializable interface

Comment: Getting same ClassCast exception, if Entity class extends 'ActiveMQObjectMessage' as well:                                                                                                                                                                public class Entity extends ActiveMQObjectMessage implements Serializable

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `<int-jms:message-driver-channel-adapter>` is configured with the `extract-payload="false".

In that case the entire `JmsMessage` is presented as a `payload` of Spring Integration Message. But as you see your `ServiceActivator` expects exactly the body of that `JmsMessage`.

Comment: Yes, I have set `extract-payload="false".  How should I solve this? I need to read both headers as well a body.

Comment: Spring Integration maps all JMS headers to MessageHeaders. Plus converts JmsMessage.body to the payload. So, leave service method as is, but try without `extract-payload`. Looks like you have confuse with JMS Message and Spring Integration Message. Please read JMS chapter in the Spring Integration Reference Manual carefully .